# XML to XSL transformation

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am new to XML. I am trying to convert the following XMl file

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <parent original_id="OI123" id="I123">
        <custompanel panel="cp"></custompanel>
    </parent>
```

into the following HTML

```
<html>
    <body><div xmlAttribute="{"original-id":"OI123","id":"I123"}">
               <p xmlAttribute={"panel":"cp"}/>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

XML tag `<parent>` should be converted to `<div>` and `<custompanel>` should be converted to `<p>` tag.

I have read the XSTL documentation from W3CSchool but still I am not exactly sure how to approach the problem.Can anyone help me with it?
The custom attribute needs to be stored in xmlAttribute as JSONObject.

Comment: W3Schools is not the best ressource there is unfortunately. There are some useful information in the [xslt tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) that you can read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick research of the correct syntax I came up with this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output
    method="xml"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    indent="yes"
    encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:template match="parent">
        <html>
            <body>
                <div xmlAttribute="{{'original-id':'{@original_id}','id':'{@id}'}}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="custompanel">
        <p xmlAttribute="{{'panel':'{@panel}'}}" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The tricky part is espacing the `{}` for the JSON, which we build ourselves. You need two curly braces `{{` to have a literal one. Also you need to use single quotes `'` inside the attributes as double quotes would be escaped to `&quot;`. You can access attributes with the `@foo` selector, but now you need to use actual `{}` to make the processor recognize it should do something.

I guess that your actual file has more than one `<parent>`. In that case you need to have a root element around it, and you need to adjust the XSLT. Add another `<xsl:template match="/">` and move the HTML frame there.

Comment: can we not create a generic XSL file which will fetch all the attributes.Because i am trying to create a XSL file which will not take the attribute names to create the JSON object in xmlAttribute so that If i have one more attribute "term"=1 in parent tag, i dont need to change my XSL file.Can we find the total attributes and iterate through them one by one using their index or something

Comment: You should ask a new question for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387664/iterating-through-attributes-using-xslt